# POST request failed due to Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: java, angular, web-services, jersey

I am trying to send a POST request using Angular 2.0 from my ionic app to the following Url  https://somedomain.com/MyTest/rest/register/post 
But the POST request is failing due to following error in console. I have already added necessary headers in the POST Response, but still its failing the request. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**Console Error:**
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**//This is the REST Api POST resource:**

```
@Path("/register")
public class JSONService{
@POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response createPlayerInJSON(RegisterPlayer player) { 
        String result="false";
        int x = 0;      

        try {

        JSONObject requestedJSON = new JSONObject(player);
        String p_Name = requestedJSON.getString("name");
        String p_Email = requestedJSON.getString("email");
        String p_Mobile = requestedJSON.getString("mobile");
        String p_Password = requestedJSON.getString("password");
        String p_Company = requestedJSON.getString("company");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        SoccerUtils dbConnection = new SoccerUtils();
        Connection conn = dbConnection.getWeekendDBConnection(); 

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO              mycoolmap.weekendsoccer_login values(default,?,?,?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, p_Name);
        ps.setString(2, p_Email);
        ps.setString(3, p_Mobile);
        ps.setString(4, p_Password);
        ps.setString(5, p_Company);
        
        x = ps.executeUpdate();
        
        if(x==1){
            result = "Successfully Registered";
        }
        conn.close();
        return Response.ok("{\"name\":" + requestedJSON.getString("name") + ",\"email\":" + requestedJSON.getString("email") + ", \"mobile\":" + requestedJSON.getString("mobile") + ", \"password\":" + requestedJSON.getString("password") + ", \"company\":" + requestedJSON.getString("company") + "}")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, Accept")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .build();
    }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Response.ok("{ \"name\":\"\"}")
                .build();

        }


    }

}
```

// **Angular 2.0 POST request:**
The function below is called when form submitted using NgForm
//signup.ts, subscribing Post method

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DataService } from '../../app/dataservice/data.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-signup',
 templateUrl: 'signup.html',
})
export class SignupPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public dataService: DataService) {
 }
 goBackToLogin() {
   this.navCtrl.pop();
 }
 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   this.dataService.registerPlayer(form.value).subscribe();
 }
}
```

// Dataservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
 apiPath: string = 'http://somedomain.com/MyTest/rest/';
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
 registerPlayer(player) {
   return this.httpClient.post(this.apiPath + 'register/post', player);
 }
}
```

Comment: You have to configure a filter for CORS based on the framework you are using. In JSONService you have a POST api configured and preflight means OPTIONS call. OPTIONS call is made by browser just before making the actual POST call, and if that doesn't succeed your POST call wont be made, and this is exactly what is happening with you.

Refer this - http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare: I have configured the CORS Filter. Now its sending the POST request, but I can't login into the app with login details now. CORS details as `response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      //      "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
    //response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    System.out.println(response.getHeaders());`